# JQuery detect inserted image after submitting through form input type="file"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to detect an image submited through a form so I can proceed with the execution of some more code. The image is submited throw a `form input type="file"` and than rendered in the page throw ajax using jquery.form.js plugin.

I've tryed the `on.load` method but it seems to only work with images called in the file code.

```
$('.img_set').on('loaded', function (){
    alert();
});
```

And:

```
$(".img_set").on('load', function() {
  alert('I loaded!');
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

I've also tryed the plugin from https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded but didn't work as I was hopping to work.

Is there a way to have something that can detect when a image is submitted, than loaded to the DOM of the page?

**UPDATE**
upload handler

```
$('.photoimg').on('change', function (){
    $('.db_result').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" />'); 
    $('.imageform').ajaxForm({ target: $(this).closest('.child')}).submit();
    $('.db_result').delay(500).queue(function(n) {
            $(this).html('');
    });
    $('.child').on('load','.img_set', function() {
        alert('new image loaded');
    });
});
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to detect when the user has completed the file selection dialog? Or are you uploading the image out-of-band using Flash or an iframe and need to know when the upload is complete?

Comment: submitted? - Are you using ajax to handle the images upload? How is the image loaded in the first place?

Comment: The image is loading throw the jquery.form.js plugin and it is using ajax to render the image in the page

Answer (score 0):

It's still somewhat unclear exactly what you're asking for but assuming that the file is successfully uploaded and an image tag is added to some container on the page, you should be able to detect when the new image has been loaded by delegating the load event to the container using the selector as a filter.

```
$('#img_container').on('load','.img_set', function() {
    alert('new image loaded');
});
```

Using delegation allows the handler to apply both to images loaded when the page is first rendered and elements that are dynamically added to the page later.

Comment: didn't work. instead of seeing if the image has finished loading is there a way to see if a new img tag has been create?

Comment: @circle73 - are you adding this handler on page load or in the upload handler? If you add it on page load, it should detect when the image has finished loading. It needs to be in place before the image has finished loading or it won't catch the event.

Comment: @circle73 - move the load event handler outside the change handler. It only needs to be applied once.  Also, where are you adding the image element to the DOM?